# JLabels in a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

I have a scrollpane in which i want to add multiple `jlabel`.
This is the code..

```
JPanel panelEast = new JPanel();
    panelEast.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Notifiche", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    panelEast.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,120));
    panelEast.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("label1");
    lblNewLabel_3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Home.class.getResource("/it/polimi/icon/contact.png")));
    lblNewLabel_3.setBounds(10, 81, 240, 52);
    panelEast.add(lblNewLabel_3);

    JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("label2");
    label_3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Home.class.getResource("/it/polimi/icon/verified.png")));
    label_3.setBounds(new Rectangle(4, 0, 0, 0));
    label_3.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
    label_3.setBounds(10, 30, 240, 52);
    panelEast.add(label_3);

    JLabel label_4 = new JLabel("label3");
    label_4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Home.class.getResource("/it/polimi/icon/verified.png")));
    label_4.setBounds(new Rectangle(4, 0, 0, 0));
    label_4.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
    label_4.setBounds(10, 131, 240, 52);
    panelEast.add(label_4);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panelEast,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    pan2.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

And does not work, any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

`JScrollPane` relies on the layout manager API in order to calculate the preferred size of the container it is showing and determine when that view is larger than itself and it should show the scroll bars

Comment: Since you didn't actually describe a problem, I could only guess that the scroll bars are not showing when you expect them to, and since the Swing API relies on the layout manager API to do, well basically, everything, a `null` layout is the first significant sign of problems. Also, an out of context snippet of code makes it very, very hard to "guess" at the root of your problem and make suggestions about appropriate solutions

Comment: (1+) @Fr4ncx, `but it does not solve the problem` - yes using [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) WILL solve the problem. Get rid of the null layout and get rid of the `setBounds(...)`. Post your updated code that does use layout managers if you still have a problem.